# ViewPager not visible on return after navigating from another Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have got classic **Bottom Navigation** created by default with 3 TABs (*FragmentOne, FragmentTwo and FragmentThree*).
The first fragment (FragmentOne) has **ViewPager** with two static inner Fragments (*FragmentInner1 and FragmentInner2*).

When app starts evrything is fine so at the **FragmentOne** we can see **FragmentInner1** and can navigate to **FragmentInner2**.

But after navigating from **FragmentTwo** to **FragmentOne** ***the FragmentInner1 is not visible.*** That is a problem.

I guess we should recreate it somehow?
I investigated manual from here https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html  and https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#PagerTitleStrip but it does not help and my code looks the same way.

Please help. Thank you!

**FragmentOne**

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

    //This is our viewPager
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    //Fragments
    FragmentInner1 fragmentInner1;
    FragmentInner2 fragmentInner2;

    ViewPagerAdapter adapter;

    private View view;

    public FragmentOne() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_one, container, false);

        //Initializing viewPager
        viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });

        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        return view;
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        adapter  = new ViewPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
        fragmentInner1=new FragmentInner1();
        fragmentInner2=new FragmentInner2();
        adapter.addFragment(fragmentInner1);
        adapter.addFragment(fragmentInner2);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context)
    {
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

**ViewPagerAdapter**

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = mFragmentList.get(position);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    }
}
```

**FragmentInner1**

```
public class FragmentInner1 extends Fragment {

    public static FragmentInner1 newInstance( ) {
        FragmentInner1 fragment = new FragmentInner1();
        return fragment;
    }

    public FragmentInner1() {
    }    

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {     
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_inner1, container, false);
    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to Use `getChildFragmentManager()` For **Viewpager** to adapt Popback Feature.

```
adapter  = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
```

This is Because the Viewpager have multiple Fragments where Viewpager itself or is holded by another Fragment. So the Child Fragment is to Be Invoked and Used.

[You Can Refer this Documentation on ChildFragmentManager()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager())